# Azure CloudDrive HTTPS Uri

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-clouddrive

From [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg436003.aspx) it says that the **connection string** for connecting to the storage account must be **HTTP and not HTTPS**.

When I use this constructor:

```
public CloudDrive (
    Uri uri,
    StorageCredentials credentials
)
```

Does that mean the **Uri** to the page blob must also be HTTP and not HTTPS? I am a bit confused regarding which parameter (*or both together*) fits the 'connection string' description.

This scenario does not seem to be easily testable in dev emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `URI` (*think of as the server-portion of the connection string*) to the page blob represents the **namespace + container + blob** of your storage account. The `credentials` represent the user/pass which together with the `URI` comprise the connection string to the Azure cloud storage service.

The `URI` will always be HTTP assuming you are using the local emulator.

```cs
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
```

When deploying to Azure, the `URI` scheme will be [whatever you assign it in the service configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758697.aspx) (*ServiceDefinition.csdef / ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg*).

```cs
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("CloudDrive.DataConnectionString");
```

You would just want to assign `CloudDrive.DataConnectionString` to have `DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http` (*the default if omitted, but you could be explicit*).

#### ServiceDefinition.csdef

```xml
<ServiceDefinition>
  <WebRole>
    <!-- .... -->
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="CloudDrive.DataConnectionString" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

#### ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg

```xml
<ServiceConfiguration>
  <Role>
    <ConfigurationSettings>
     <Setting name="CloudDrive.DataConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=YOURNAMESPACE;AccountKey=YOURKEY" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

Comment: [This MSDN blog post states HTTPS is not supported for `CloudDrive`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tconte/archive/2010/04/07/using-windows-azure-drive-part-2-modifying-my-application-to-use-the-drive.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0)...I will have to try and get back to you.

Comment: All my connection strings must be Https, so it seems the right way to use that constructor would be to ensure the uri portion is http:

`CloudStorageAccount httpsAccount = ...;`
`var blobUri = httpsAccount.GetContainerReference("mycontainer").GetPageBlobReference("myblob").Uri;`
`var httpBlobUri = new UriBuilder(blobUri){Scheme ="http", Port = 80}.Uri;`
`CloudDrive cloudDrive = new CloudDrive(httpBlobUri, httpsAccount.Credentials);`

Comment: Why do you need the connection strings all defined as HTTPS? You can have multiple connection strings defined - just use a non-HTTPS one for `CloudDrive` interaction. When HTTPS is supported - you don't need to build/republish, you can just change the running configuration.

Comment: unfortunatly that part is out of my control, i'm just working under the assumption of receiving a https connection string.

i will try my earlier comment of rebuilding the uri to be http instead of https.